# How secure are skype calls from wireless device / cell-phone?

Tags: security, wireless-networking, encryption, skype

I read that skype is [quite secure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skype_security). I wanted to ask if the same holds when it's used from a wireless device (say, laptop) or a mobile phone (iphone, android). This assumes it's connecting via a secure wireless network. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data stream is encrypted [by the Skype client](http://www.skype.com/intl/en/security/detailed-security/faq/). If the client is running on your local device then it is encrypted before it is sent across the air.

Answer (score 2):

It uses the same security measures to communicate as it does on a regular computer. Even when not connecting through secure channels, the protocol uses Skype secures the data being sent.